# Flutter dart_ping package is not working. So how to ping some remote ip like 172.18.43.140?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

https://pub.dev/packages/dart_ping#-readme-tab-

I used this package to check ping. But it does not work correctly.

**here is my code:**

```dart
pingTheGoogle() async {
  var stream = await ping("8.8.8.8", times: 5);

  print("Pinging google.com");
  stream.listen((d) {
    print(d.time.inMilliseconds);
  });
}
```

**Here is the output of the following code:-**

> I/flutter ( 8390): Pinging google.com

That's it. No output is printed about the ping. I think the listening part is not working properly. I need this package because in my app I want to ping to the various IP. The listening part is never get executed. My connection status is also ok.

The network connection is fine and all features using the internet are working fine. But I need to ping some remote IP.

Comment: This package was written for PC and Linux, it is not working for Android

Comment: Is there any package available to ping in android and ios?

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is an older post, this package DOES work with Android.
( This example is based on v3.0.0 ) .

```
pingTheGoogle() async {
    var ping = Ping('8.8.8.8', times: 5);
    var stream = ping.stream;

    stream.listen((event) {
    print(event);
  });
}
```